# How does the call stack unwinding process exactly work, for function calls? - C++

Tags: c++, callstack

I am solving the TowerOfHanoi problem, using stacks in STL (C++). But I am not sure why I am getting this warning at line 6703:

[image: Warning C26444]

When I get this warning, I don't get the intended result on running the program. The program shows no output on the console window and the console window simply says - "Press any key to continue..."

But, when I put a return statement in front of line 6703, the warning goes away and, I get the correct result on the output console window:

[image: Appending return, solves the issue]

And, following is the output on the console, when I append `return` in front of the function call (at line 6703) -

[image: Correct output, when I append return in front of the function]

Why do I have to append `return` in front of the function call, for it to work correctly?

If we look at the call stack, there are three call stacks created:
1. One for main
2. The second for `towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 3)`
3. The third for `towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 2)`

After that, stack unwinding process begins -
3. `towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 2)` returns stack3 to `towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 3)`
2. Now, `towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 3)` in turn returns stack3 to `main()`

Am I correct on how the stack unwinding process is going on? And, return is essential at line 6703: `return towerOfHanoi(stack1, stack2, stack3, n - 1)` - because if it is absent, we will fail to return the stack3 to `main`? -

[image: StackFrame unwinding process]

Can you please explain me the stack frame unwinding process better?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the call stack unwinding or whatever. The return value is used to print the results not while generating it. And please copy the code and dont provide picutres

Comment: There is a mountain of literature surrounding this topic. Did you do any cursory research?

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED, yes, I did some research before posting this topic. But I was perplexed by the error C26444. While posting the question, I realized that if a recursive function returns a value, we have to put return in front of the function signature, everywhere the function appears. Nonetheless I posted the question, for the benefit of others, who may encounter this error. To be sure, I asked in my post,  "Am I correct, how the stack unwinding process is going on?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 2) returns stack3 to towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 3) beacuse of

```
if (n == 2) {
    return stack3;
}
```

but

towerOfHanoi(stack1,stack2,stack3, 3) doesnt return anything to main. Because you didnt provided a return statement at the end function.